# Change geom_text label angle in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have the following chart I have built using `ggplot` + `ggplotly`.

I am trying to add labels to the red (median) and blue (percentile 90%) vertical lines without luck.
Please advise how should I fix it.

The code I have used:

```
p1 <- ggplot(users_d_total %>% filter(isSame, D_rank == 2), aes(x = D, fill = as.factor(train_user_id))) +
  geom_density(alpha = .3) +
  labs(title = paste0("Without Normalization Analysis [K = 2]")) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Users") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = by_two) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(D)), col = 'red', linetype = 1, size = 1) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = median(D), y = 1, label = "Median"), hjust = 1, angle = 90, colour= "red") + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = quantile(D, probs = .9)), col = 'blue', linetype = 1, size = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = quantile(D, probs = .9), y = 1, label = "90th Percentile"), hjust = 1, angle = 90, colour = "blue") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

ggplotly(p1)
```

I want the text to be vertical but using the answer from [How to add legend for vertical lines in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885769/how-to-add-legend-for-vertical-lines-in-ggplot) didn't help me.

[image]

Comment: Does it  work without plotly?

Comment: @PoGibas sure it does, I need these labels + plotly functionality.

Comment: This is not possible until [this gets fixed](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/709). (MWE: `plotly::ggplotly(ggplot() + geom_text(aes(1, 1, label = 1), angle = 90))`)

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas it's more than a year after this bug have been reported and no one fixed it....
Any suggestions how to solve it? Maybe something creative you can teach me to bypass?

Comment: `+ coord_flip()` :-) And first of all, I would use boxplot/violinplot. Or add annotation of `geom_vline` to legend

Comment: Also, just a general tip, but you might try to `log2` x-axis for visualization purpose.

Comment: Yes I am aware :) hope one day they will fix it.